# Post Not Publishing to Page via FaceBook API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

All I am trying to do is post to a page using the API.  This task was extremely simple using Twitter; but with FaceBook, it has been very challenging.

I am using the following code:

```
string url = @"https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed?message=Hello&access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}";

WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream data = client.OpenRead(url);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

It returns data like this:

```
{"data":[{"story":"Page updated their cover photo.","created_time":"2017-03-13T22:49:56+0000","id":"1646548358..._164741855..."}...
```

But, the post is never seen on the page!  How can I successfully post from my app to my page?

Comment: I'm super new to Facebooks api. But I just skimmed through the documentation. It seems like your request type needs to be POST which it isn't in your code. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post

Comment: you need a page token. right now you are using an app token. hit the docs about those.

Answer (score 1):

Your request should be a POST request as the data you're getting back suggests this is a GET request.

Also you need the `publish_pages` permission to successfully post to a page

Comment: I am sending a post now, but it says, "403 forbidden."  I don't see where to specify `publish_pages` do you know how to get there?  I have google'd it and not found any direct answers.

Comment: Use the graph api to get a token that includes this permission use it. Later on in your app you need to specify that as part of the scope when connecting to facebook.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions using the information here, you can request for permissions on login using the `scope`

Comment: I am trying to avoid having to login.  I am not authenticating multiple users; I am only trying to authenticate the app to post to the page (as the page).  Or, alternatively, authenticate my personal account to post to the page (as the page).  Could you share some code to accomplish this?